# Querry wpa_supplicant with which AP is it associated

Tags: wpa-supplicant

I call

```
    wpa_supplicant -c"$CONF" -i"$IFACE" -B
```

where $CONF is a file with many `network={}` definitions. `wpa_supplicant` does connect to any one of those in range.

*How can I query with which AP is my laptop associated?*

I tried adding `-dd` and parsing the output. What I found is:

```
Priority group 1
   id=3 ssid='UP-Campus'
Priority group 0
   id=0 ssid='Sauron'
   id=1 ssid='futurenet'
```

Can I rely on this, that `wpa_supplicant` fill surely connect to 'UP-Campus'.

And another question, does `wpa_supplicant` reconnect? If I walk out of the range of one of the cells in the config file and walk into the range of another, will it reconnect?

Comment: Have a look at `wpa_cli`. The man page is outdated, `wpa_cli help` will list all commands. Yes, `wpa_supplicant` will reconnect if configured properly. Yes, it will respect priorities. It will also connect to lower priorities if higher priorities are not available...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few ways on the command line to query for the AP you are connected to (Change `wlan0` to the name of your wireless Interface):

1)

```
iw wlan0 link
```

2)

```
iwconfig wlan0
```

3)

```
wpa_cli -i wlan0 STATUS
```

Regarding your other questions, I can confirm from my experience what @dirkt has written in his comment:
**First connection:**
The first Connection will always be to the Access Point with the highest priority at the Moment.
**Connection lost:**
Once this connection is lost, it will connect to the one AP that has the highest priority of the remaining available ones.
**Already connected, but new AP with higher priority available:**
When a new AP becomes available with higher priority than the one you are currently connected to, it will switch the connection to the one with the higher priority within a few seconds.